# Get North,South,East,West street names from Geocode in Google Map

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented property search through google maps and each property will be marked as a pin in the google map. In this I need, User can able to know the street names of single property (geocode) for North, South, East, West, NorthEast, NorthWest, SouthWest and SouthEast directions.I just need to list out each direction street names.

For example I am searching for below property it has to return

Property : `18,Maha street,Coimbatore,Tamilnadu (27.268255,-95.55666)`

```
North : Main street
South : Anna street
East : River road
West : School street
NorthEast : KMSkj Street
NorthWest : Ring road
SouthWest : Hasbdagh Road
SouthEast : Outer ring road
```

Is this possible to achieve in Google Map?

If I get geocode for all direction  then we can apply reverse geocode right?

Comment: This can't be done with Geocoding API, geocoding just converts address to lat/long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by server side geocode process, below are the methods involved:

```
    public GeocoderLocation Locate(string query)
    {
        GeocoderLocation N = new GeocoderLocation();
        GeocoderLocation S = new GeocoderLocation();
        GeocoderLocation E = new GeocoderLocation();
        GeocoderLocation W = new GeocoderLocation();
        GeocoderLocation NE = new GeocoderLocation();
        GeocoderLocation NW = new GeocoderLocation();
        GeocoderLocation SE = new GeocoderLocation();
        GeocoderLocation SW = new GeocoderLocation();

        WebRequest request = WebRequest
           .Create("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&size=750x700&address="
              + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query));

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                XDocument document = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(stream));

                List<XElement> longitudeElement = document.Descendants("lng").ToList();
                List<XElement> latitudeElement = document.Descendants("lat").ToList();

                if (latitudeElement != null && latitudeElement.Count == 3 && longitudeElement != null && longitudeElement.Count == 3)
                {
                    NE.Longitude = Double.Parse(longitudeElement[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    NE.Latitude = Double.Parse(latitudeElement[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    SW.Longitude = Double.Parse(longitudeElement[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    SW.Latitude = Double.Parse(latitudeElement[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    NW.Latitude = NE.Latitude;
                    NW.Longitude = SW.Longitude;

                    SE.Latitude = SW.Latitude;
                    SE.Longitude = NE.Longitude;
                }
                List<GeocoderLocation> NList = new List<GeocoderLocation>();
                NList.Add(NE);
                NList.Add(NW);
                N = GetCentralGeoCoordinate(NList);

                List<GeocoderLocation> SList = new List<GeocoderLocation>();
                SList.Add(SE);
                SList.Add(SW);
                S = GetCentralGeoCoordinate(SList);

                List<GeocoderLocation> EList = new List<GeocoderLocation>();
                EList.Add(SE);
                EList.Add(NE);
                E = GetCentralGeoCoordinate(EList);

                List<GeocoderLocation> WList = new List<GeocoderLocation>();
                WList.Add(NW);
                WList.Add(SW);
                W = GetCentralGeoCoordinate(WList);

                string Address_ShortName = string.Empty;
                string Address_country = string.Empty;
                string Address_administrative_area_level_1 = string.Empty;
                string Address_administrative_area_level_2 = string.Empty;
                string Address_administrative_area_level_3 = string.Empty;
                string Address_colloquial_area = string.Empty;
                string Address_locality = string.Empty;
                string Address_sublocality = string.Empty;
                string Address_neighborhood = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname1 = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname2 = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname3 = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname4 = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname5 = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname6 = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname7 = string.Empty;
                string Address_streetname8 = string.Empty;

                if (N != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(N.Longitude.ToString(), N.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood,out Address_streetname1);

                    txtNorth.Text = Address_streetname1;
                }

                if (W != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(W.Longitude.ToString(), W.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood, out Address_streetname2);

                    txtWest.Text = Address_streetname2;
                }

                if (S != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(S.Longitude.ToString(), S.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood,out Address_streetname3);

                    txtSouth.Text = Address_streetname3;
                }

                if (NW != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(NW.Longitude.ToString(), NW.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood, out Address_streetname4);

                    txtNorthWest.Text = Address_streetname4;
                }

                if (NE != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(NE.Longitude.ToString(), NE.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood, out Address_streetname5);

                    txtNorthEast.Text = Address_streetname5;
                }

                if (SE != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(SE.Longitude.ToString(), SE.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood,out Address_streetname6);

                    txtSouthEast.Text = Address_streetname6;
                }

                if (SW != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(SW.Longitude.ToString(), SW.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood, out Address_streetname7);

                    txtSouthWest.Text = Address_streetname7;
                }

                if (E != null)
                {
                    string str = ReverseGeoLoc(E.Longitude.ToString(), E.Latitude.ToString(), out Address_ShortName,
                        out Address_country, out Address_administrative_area_level_1,
                        out Address_administrative_area_level_2, out Address_administrative_area_level_3,
                        out Address_colloquial_area, out Address_locality, out Address_sublocality,
                        out  Address_neighborhood, out Address_streetname8);

                    txtEast.Text = Address_streetname8;
                }

            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    public GeocoderLocation GetCentralGeoCoordinate(IList<GeocoderLocation> geoCoordinates)
    {
        if (geoCoordinates.Count == 1)
        {
            return geoCoordinates.Single();
        }

        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double z = 0;

        foreach (var geoCoordinate in geoCoordinates)
        {
            var latitude = geoCoordinate.Latitude * Math.PI / 180;
            var longitude = geoCoordinate.Longitude * Math.PI / 180;

            x += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
            y += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
            z += Math.Sin(latitude);
        }

        var total = geoCoordinates.Count;

        x = x / total;
        y = y / total;
        z = z / total;

        var centralLongitude = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        var centralSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        var centralLatitude = Math.Atan2(z, centralSquareRoot);

        return new GeocoderLocation
        {
            Latitude = centralLatitude * 180 / Math.PI,
            Longitude = centralLongitude * 180 / Math.PI

        };
    }

    public static string ReverseGeoLoc(string longitude, string latitude,
    out string Address_ShortName,
    out string Address_country,
    out string Address_administrative_area_level_1,
    out string Address_administrative_area_level_2,
    out string Address_administrative_area_level_3,
    out string Address_colloquial_area,
    out string Address_locality,
    out string Address_sublocality,
    out string Address_neighborhood,
     out string Address_streetname)
    {

        Address_ShortName = "";
        Address_country = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_1 = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_2 = "";
        Address_administrative_area_level_3 = "";
        Address_colloquial_area = "";
        Address_locality = "";
        Address_sublocality = "";
        Address_neighborhood = "";
        Address_streetname = "";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            doc.Load("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=false");
            XmlNode element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/status");
            if (element.InnerText == "ZERO_RESULTS")
            {
                return ("No data available for the specified location");
            }
            else
            {

                element = doc.SelectSingleNode("//GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address");

                string longname = "";
                string shortname = "";
                string typename = "";
                bool fHit = false;


                XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        longname = xn["long_name"].InnerText;
                        shortname = xn["short_name"].InnerText;
                        typename = xn["type"].InnerText;


                        fHit = true;
                        switch (typename)
                        {
                            //Add whatever you are looking for below
                            case "country":
                                {
                                    Address_country = longname;
                                    Address_ShortName = shortname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "locality":
                                {
                                    Address_locality = longname;
                                    //Address_locality = shortname; //Om Longname visar sig innehålla konstigheter kan man använda shortname istället
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "sublocality":
                                {
                                    Address_sublocality = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "neighborhood":
                                {
                                    Address_neighborhood = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "colloquial_area":
                                {
                                    Address_colloquial_area = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_1":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_1 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_2":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_2 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }

                            case "administrative_area_level_3":
                                {
                                    Address_administrative_area_level_3 = longname;
                                    break;
                                }


                            case "route":
                                {
                                    Address_streetname = longname;
                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                fHit = false;
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }


                }

                return (element.InnerText);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class GeocoderLocation
    {
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}, {1}", Latitude, Longitude);
        }
    }
```